# Ionic: After Image download success then image not showing in image gallary

Tags: android, ionic4

Ionic: I am downloading images using `FileTransfer.download()` it a success, but it won't show in the

image gallery unless not relaunch the image gallery app.

```
this.baseDownloadDir = ${this.file.externalRootDirectory}${this.userService.appName}/`;
downloadImage(src: string): void {
    if (!this.userService.getNetworkState()) {
      this.loaderService.showToaster(this.translateService.instant('ERROR_MESSAGES.NO_NETWORK'));
    } else {
      if (src) {
        const fileName = src.split('/');
        let imgName = fileName[fileName.length - 1];
        imgName = imgName.replace('.', `${new Date().getTime().toString()}.`);
        const downloadPath = this.baseDownloadDir + imgName;
        this.fileTransfer = this.transfer.create();
        this.diagnostic.isExternalStorageAuthorized().then((isAuthorized) => {
          if (isAuthorized) {
            this.fileDownload(src, downloadPath);
          } else {
            this.diagnostic.requestExternalStorageAuthorization().then((status) => {
              if (status === 'GRANTED') {
                this.fileDownload(src, downloadPath);
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }

  fileDownload(src, downloadPath) {
    this.fileTransfer.download(src, downloadPath).then((FileEntry) => {
      this.loaderService.showToaster(this.translateService.instant('ERROR_MESSAGES.DOWNLOAD_SUCCESS'));
    });
  }
```

Comment: Have you checked in a folder, file available there after download?

Comment: Yes, File is available. but it didn't see image in the image gallery.
If the image gallery is already running in the background then it's need to exit from the image gallery app and then again open the image gallery and it works.

I tried NgZone as well on **this.fileTransfer.download**